# Не находится файл на локальном сервере

Tags: html, css, png

Всё происходит на Денвере
Файл находящийся в папке css при css коде: 'background: url(../images/sprite.png) -182px -91px;' в браузере выдаёт ошибку 404, ссылаясь на то что в папке отсутствует этот файл, хотя из файла html в главной папке файл находится[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну лично я на скрине не вижу в папке пнг файла спрайт.

Comment: @AlexSazonov справа в углу.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по коду css - все должно работать `../` - поднимает на уровень вверх а `/images/` - переходит в папку изображений, где ищется sprite.png

Сделайте следующее - откройте страницу в браузере, в консоли где ошибка 404 нажмите на ссылку, которая там выводится и посмотрите к какому пути она ведет.

Это поможет понять в какую директорию у вас пытается обратиться код. Возможно подключаемый вами файл css лежит не там, где вы думаете.